# binary to bcd verilog output is always x

Tags: verilog

I have a binary to bcd convertor module that uses the shift add 3 algorithm as follows :

```
module BCD(
    input wire [7:0] binary,
    output wire [3:0] Hundreds, 
    output wire [3:0] Tens, 
    output wire [3:0] Ones
);
integer i;
reg [11:0] bcd;
initial begin
    bcd = 12'b000000000000;
    for(i=7;i>=0;i=i-1) begin
       bcd[11:0] = { bcd[10:0], binary[i] };
       if(bcd[3:0] >= 5) bcd[3:0] = bcd[3:0] + 2'b11;
       if(bcd[7:4] >= 5) bcd[7:4] = bcd[7:4] + 2'b11;
    end
end
assign Hundreds = bcd[11:8];
assign Tens = bcd[7:4];
assign Ones = bcd[3:0];
endmodule;
```

and a Test bench for it as follows :

```
module BCD_Testbunch();
reg [7:0] binary;
wire [3:0] bcd_u;
wire [3:0] bcd_t;
wire [3:0] bcd_h;
integer i;
initial begin
    binary = 8'b00000000;
    $monitor("t = %g\t || Binary =%b (%d) BCD = %d %d %d",$time,binary,binary,bcd_h,bcd_t,bcd_u);
    for(i=1;i<=8'b11111111;i=i+1)
        #5 binary = binary + 1;
end
BCD B (binary,bcd_h,bcd_t,bcd_u);
endmodule;
```

yet my bcd output is always 0 x x whatever the value of the binary input

Comment: The `initial` block inside `BCD` looks strange to me. I don't think you want to update the outputs of `BCD` only *once* at the beginning, but *every time* the input changes. I can't say if this is correct, but try using `always @(*)` instead of `initial`.

Comment: thanks for your help it worked after changing the `initial` to `always @(*)` in bcd

Answer (score 0):

As @mkrieger1 pointed out in comments I changed the `initial` to `always @(*)` in bcd module And everything is working now